# What is causing this syntax error while parsing JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string in javascript:

```
var test = '{"test":"\\-"}'
```

When I try to parse this as JSON with the following:

```
JSON.parse(test)
```

or with:

```
$.parseJSON(test)
```

I get a SyntaxError of type "unexpected_token_number".
This the value for the `"test"` attribute is a user enterable field. How should I properly escape this field?

Comment: I was also facing some similar problem, I first stingified my JSON and then parsed it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`'{"test":"\\-"}'` will be interpreted as JavaScript string, with the result being `{"test":"\-"}`.

As you can see in [these diagrams](http://json.org/), `\-` is not a valid escape sequence (valid are `\"`, `\\`, `\/`, `\b`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\uxxxx`).

[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) also gives the error

```
Parse error on line 2:
{    "test": "\-"}
-------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

If you want two backslashes in the JSON you have to escape them in the JavaScript string as well, so you'd end up with

```
var test = '{"test": "\\\\-"}';
```

Otherwise, omit it:

```
var test = '{"test": "-"}';
```

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "test": "\-"
}
```

Inside a string, a `\` character [must be followed by](http://json.org/) `"`, `\`, `/`, `b`, `f`, `n`, `r`, `t` or `u????` where the question marks represent hexadecimal digits.

You probably want the JSON to look like this:

```
{
    "test": "\\-"
}
```

And are failing to convert it to a JavaScript string properly, but not escaping the `\` characters for JavaScript.

```
var test = '{"test":"\\\\-"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var test = '{"test":"\-"}'
JSON.parse(test)
```

Is that what you wanted? To have: `{test: "-"}`?

Otherwiste:

```
var test = '{"test":"\\\\-"}'
JSON.parse(test)
```

To have: `{test:"\-"}`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the value of test to be? The `\` is an escape character in JavaScript. Assuming that you're trying to escape it and that you want the value of test to be `\-`, this will work:

```
var test = '{"test":"\\\\-"}'

//Result: { test="\-"}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try to parse that string, I get "bad escaped character".

The reason is that you are escaping a character that doesn't need escaping. The `\\` in the string literal is an escaped backslash, so the string contains the escape code `\-`. A dash doesn't need escaping, so that escape code is not allowed by the JSON parser.

If you want to put an escaped backslash in the JSON you have to escape it to put it in a literal string:

```
var test = '{"test":"\\\\-"}'
```